# What will be the last term of the resulting series if we recursively apply integration by part infinite times?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am using integration by part concept in my proofs in which I will use it recursively infinite times.

In this regard, I am wondering, what will be the last term of the resulting series which will have infinite order derivative of the first function.

Can anybody give me abstract mathematical form or the resulting infinite sum?

Comment: Without an example I hardly see how we can help you here, nothing proves this exists or converges

Comment: great question, but hard to be specific. Have you thought about what happens if you integrate $\sin(x)$ a lot of times?

Comment: @MatthewTowers it will just oscillate between sin and cosine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your integral is of the form $\int_I u v$ (let's say on an segment I with both $C^\infty$ functions

$\int_I uv = [u \cdot \int v]_I - \int_I (u' \int v)$

If you iterate, you'll get

$\int_I uv = [u \cdot \int V]_I - [u' \cdot \int^{\circ 2} v]_I + \cdots + (-1)^{n} [u^{(n)} \int^{\circ n+1} v]_I + (-1)^{n+1} \int_I (u^{(n+1)} \int^{\circ n+1} v)$

With $\int^{k} v$ a $k$-th primitive of $v$ and if $I  = [a,b]$, $[f]_I = f(b) - f(a)$.

Now if $\int_I (u^{(n+1)} \int^{\circ n+1} v) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, you will get
$$\int_I uv = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n [u^{(n)} \int^{\circ n+1} v]_I $$

I don't know if that's what you were looking for, but without further explanation It seems impossible to do more.

Comment: So if u is a real analytic function (or functions whose infinite derivative approaches zero) then the assumption in line 6 is satisfied.. Right?